# how to subset all the data of group based off of last value within a group in r

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataset with the following information:

- group      health condition

  - a          healthy
  - a          healthy
  - a          not healthy
  - b          healthy
  - b          healthy
  - c          healthy
  - c          healthy
  - c          not healthy

i would like to somehow subset the data by scanning each health condition in each group and if the health condition is "not healthy" in the final row of each group to subset that group's information.so that the desired output is:

- group      health condition
- a          healthy
- a          healthy
- a          not healthy
- c          healthy
- c          healthy
- c          not healthy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**With packages**, you could use dplyr or data.table here:

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% group_by(group) %>% filter(health[n()] == "N")

   group health
  (fctr) (fctr)
1      a      H
2      a      H
3      a      N
4      c      H
5      c      H
6      c      N

library(data.table)
setDT(DF)
DF[, if (health[.N] == "N") .SD, by=group]

   group health
1:     a      H
2:     a      H
3:     a      N
4:     c      H
5:     c      H
6:     c      N
```

As @docendodiscimus pointed out, you can use `last(health)` instead of `health[n()]` or `health[.N]`. Both packages have a `last` function that does this.

---

**In base,** @docendo provided:

```
subset(DF, ave(health == "N", group, FUN = function(x) tail(x, 1)))
```

And from @akrun:

```
subset(DF, group %in% group[health == "N" & !duplicated(group, fromLast=TRUE)])
```

---

**Data**. I didn't use the OP's data exactly, since it was a pain to reproduce. Instead it's:

```
  group health
1     a      H
2     a      H
3     a      N
4     b      H
5     b      H
6     b      H
7     c      H
8     c      H
9     c      N

DF = structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), health = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("H", "N"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("group", 
"health"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Another option is `subset(DF, group %in% group[health == "N" & !duplicated(group, fromLast=TRUE)])`